# How to display the category so in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

List:

```
Category: level 1
```

After select level 1, show:

```
Category: level 2 (level 3 / level 3 / level 3)

Category: level 2 (level 3 / level 3 / level 3)

Category: level 2 (level 3 / level 3 / level 3)

Category: level 2 (level 3 / level 3 / level 3)
```

Any idea or tutorial.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to build a drop down on hover? Do you have ul and li's ?

See this : jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/4jxph/2/

Comment: I'm trying to level 2:
<pre>
$args_list = array(
  'echo' => 0,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'title_li' => '',
  'depth' => 2,
  'child_of=' => $cat 
);
 if( $list = wp_list_categories($args_list)) {
  echo '<ul>' . $list . '</ul>';
 }
</pre>